# Can we mention possible users without their permission?

Tags: law, marketing

I've created many open source projects under MIT license.

Due to the inquiries I receive, stargazers, and direct communication with the people who are using them, I know many big companies who are using my open source projects.

Is there any legal issue if I show them as possible users of my open source project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Statements affirming public data are fine.

Stars and watchers on GitHub are public data - anyone can see it. If you're just making a statement about that data, you're fine - you're stating a fact, what people choose to make of it is out of your control. Something like

> BigCompanyA and BigCompanyB have starred this project on GitHub!

would be okay, for example.

I'd steer clear of making statements based on the implications of that data. You know (for a fact) that the company has starred/watched your repository; however, that doesn't necessarily imply that they use the project. They might just really like you. Unless you know for certain that they use it, I'd avoid saying they do.

## If in doubt, *ask*!

It sounds like you already have a channel of communication open with the people you're planning to claim as users. If you're not sure whether it's okay or not, use that communication channel to ask them! A quick

> Hey, do you mind if I quote you on that?

or maybe

> Hey, can I list you as a user of this project on my website?

isn't problematic - you can even tack it on to the end of a more business-focused message, if you like.

Comment: Thanks. What I see here is It is good to mention the users but with slightly different wordings and their permission. I seen many big opensource projects mentioning big companies as their users. Do they really confirm with proper authority of that company?

Comment: I'd expect they have, @AmitGupta - it doesn't have to be a huge formal process, but it seems discourteous to me to mention someone in relation to a project without confirming that you're not making incorrect assumptions.